# How can i call C# function (client-side) from JavaScript (WebPage, server-side) using WebBrowser Control?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

So i want to make a webbrowser for our project that can access, COM(serial), USB and the Bluetooth of the PC he is running, connect to a printer, then open our webpage.
 In the webpage i want to call a function from the winform Web Browser Control and give it some parameters. I searched on the web but i didnt found anything around this problem.

Is there a way to call a C# winforms client-side function from server-side webpage and pass some parameters ?

Comment: to clarify, a button on the webpage should call a winform function?

Comment: Yes, thats what im trying to achieve @John !

Comment: did the duplicate thread help? @sorin llie

Comment: Not really. The link shows how to call a function from a webpage constructed by the winform(at least thats what im understanding). I found an example on a website but stil couldnt manage it to work. Any example or help would be apreciated. I have a bit of experience with c# but none of that browser controlee stuff.

Comment: @John, anything that could help me out, buddy ?